# Cypress 10 - How to run all tests in one go?

Tags: cypress

I used to use Cypress 9 on previous projects.
By default, when running `cypress open` or `cypress open --browser chrome` used to run all tests for all React components.

However I installed Cypress 10 for the first time on a project that didn't have e2e tests yet. I added test specs, but I don't see any option to run all tests altogether.

It seems I have to run the tests one by one, clicking on each of them.

Can anyone please suggest how do I run all the tests automatically?

[image]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It's been removed in Cypress v10, here are the change notes related

> During cypress open, the ability to "Run all specs" and "Run filtered specs" has been removed. Please leave feedback around the removal of this feature here. Your feedback will help us make product decisions around the future of this feature.

The feedback page to register your displeasure is [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/discussions/21628)

---

You can create a "barrel" spec to run multiple imported specs.

I can't vouch for it working the same as v9 "Run all tests", but can't see any reason why not.

```js
// all.spec.cy.js

import './test1.spec.cy.js'    // relative paths
import './test2.spec.cy.js'
...
```

As @Constance says, reinstated in v11.20.

But still a very handy technique if you want to run a pre-defined subset of your tests.

Comment: Don't forget to exclude your barrel spec when running in CI, otherwise each test will be run twice. Add this under `e2e` in your `cypress.config.ts`:
`if (config.isTextTerminal) { return {excludeSpecPattern: ['cypress/e2e/all.spec.cy.js']}; }`

Comment: I prefer to forget about `excludeSpecPattern` and just use `--spec cypress/e2e/all.spec.cy.js` instead.

Comment: This work around is no longer needed, use the `experimentalRunAllSpecs` flag instead

Comment: Naive, not everyone updates to the latest version.

Comment: This is useful beyond `experimentalRunAllSpecs` to run subsets of tests.

Comment: Definite lifesaver that I didn't consider before. Fun note: If you're building your app with Vite instead of Webpack, `experiementalRunAllSpecs` fails if you're copying over any static files, so that was not an option for me. This barrel spec def solves my problem though, so thanks!

Answer (score 39):

In Cypress version 11.2.0 the **Run All** button has been reinstated.

You need to set `experimentalRunAllSpecs` to true in `cypress.config.js`.

Please see [Configuration - End-to-End Testing](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/experiments#End-to-End-Testing)

Answer (score 3):

If Cypress Test Runner is not a must, I suggest to utilize the CLI/Node Cmd approach

You can trigger all the test(s) by `npx cypress run`(Still the video recording & screenshot on failed steps would be saved in the respective folders) to run all or with any other cypress flags to filter out specific spec files, or browser etc.

Comment: This is also extremely fast in comparison.

Comment: true, it is by design

Answer (score 1):

As per the feedback [discussion](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/discussions/21628) there is a workaround the same as @Fody's answer that will achieve the same result as v9. Also worth noting though is the section on Continuous Integration and the Update 1 that includes a fix for preventing this workaround creating issues with the `cypress run` command.

> #### Are there any current workarounds?
>
> - Yes. If you are impacted by the omission of this feature, it is possible to achieve the same level of parity as 9.x with a workaround Gleb Bahmutov explains here: https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/run-all-specs-cypress-v10/
> - This will still inherit the same problems as the previous implementation (which is why it was removed) but it will work in certain cases where the previous implementation was not problematic for your use case

https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/discussions/21628#discussion-4098510

Comment: If test isolation is the issue (not entirely clear), it's no different from ensuring correct isolation between tests in the same spec.

Answer (score -2):

It was removed because people used it wrong.

The Test Runner is for debugging single tests. But by running all tests, then performance will quickly become a problem and crash the entire suite.

Running all tests should only be performed from the CLI.

**Sources**

- https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/681
- https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/discussions/21628

Comment: Not true - open mode can actually run a set of tests faster than run mode. If you have hundreds of tests it will naturally run slowly, but it shouldn't crash unless you're doing something weird. And there was a filter option to run a subset of the tests - where is that now?