# Filter tests using "Run all tests" in Cypress version 10+

Tags: cypress

Cypress v10 removed the button to run all my tests. We can use "barrel" tests to work around it,
ref [Cypress 10 - How to run all tests in one go?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72498151/16997707).

```js
// all.spec.cy.js

import './test1.spec.cy.js'    // relative paths
import './test2.spec.cy.js'
...
```

But is it possible to search and filter the tests to run?

For example we used to be able to do this:

[image: Cypress v9 filtering tests]

which cuts the selection from **Run 250 integration specs** down to **Run 1 integration spec**.

Apart from manually setting up multiple barrel specs, is there any way to handle this automatically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I created a test that generates **filtered** index tests.

It reads the **Search Specs** field of the Cypress runner, and the list of filtered specs underneath it. Then it writes a new index spec that only runs the filtered specs.

---

**Implementation**

First, create a folder `cypress/e2e/_generated-tests`. Inside that folder, create a new spec `_generate.cy.js`

```js
const filter = Cypress.$(parent.document.body)
  .find('div#app')
  .find('#inline-spec-list-header-search')
  .val()

const specPaths = Cypress.$(parent.document.body)
  .find('div#app')
  .find('ul').eq(0)
  .find('li')
  .map((index,el) => {
    const text = el.innerText.replace('\n', '').replace('\\', '/')
    const path = Cypress.$(el).find('a').attr('href').split('?file=')[1]
    return {
      text,
      path
    }
  })
  .filter((index, item) => item.text.endsWith('.cy.js') && !item.text.startsWith('_'))
  .map((index,item) => item.path)
  .toArray()

it('', () => {
  const indexSpecName = filter ? `_run-[${filter}]-filter.cy.js` : '_run-all.cy.js'

  const content = specPaths.map(specPath => {
    const relativePath = specPath.replace('cypress/e2e', '')
    return `context('${specPath}', () => require('..${relativePath}'))`  
  }).join('\n')

  cy.writeFile(`./cypress/e2e/_generated-tests/${indexSpecName}`, content)
})
```

To use it, first run the `_generate.cy.js` spec. Then filter the spec tree as required, and re-run this spec.

It will create a new index spec under `_generated-tests` with a name of `_run-[searchTerm]-filter.cy.js`.

This code is configured to my preferences, like spec extensions are `.cy.js` but you can adjust to suit your own requirements.

---

To use `cypress run` excluding all the generated index files, add `cypress/e2e/_generated-tests/**/*` to the `excludeSpecPattern` configuration.