# Filter tests by tags (e.g cypress-grep) when using "Run all tests"

Tags: cypress, cypress-grep

Following on from my question [Filter tests using "Run all tests" in Cypress version 10+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74176124/filter-tests-using-run-all-tests-in-cypress-version-10), can we apply tagged test filters to the Cypress GUI?

For example, if I add [cypress-grep](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/tree/develop/npm/grep) to the project I can then use tags against each test like this

```js
it('tests for smoke', {tags: ['@smoke']}, () => {
})

it('tests for fire', {tags: ['@fire']}, () => {
})
```

I can then run `npx cypress open --env grep=@smoke,grepFilterTests=true` from a script.

Is it possible to extend the "Run all tests with filter" to enter the tag `@smoke` in the GUI and make an ad-hoc run of the smoke tests?

I realize the above npx command does the same job, but the steps are long and time wasting when all I want to do is run my smokes during development changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can filter tests dynamically by **tag** if following a convention for prefixing tags with `@`.

`cypress-grep` is normally called in `cypress/support/e2e.js`, but it also works if you call it at the top of your generated test script.

This is the pattern of the generated test. The first few lines invoke `cypress-grep` to enable filtering by the tag `@smoke`.

```js
// generated script for specs filtered with "@smoke"

import cypressGrep from '@cypress/grep';
Cypress.env('grepTags', '@smoke');
cypressGrep();

context('cypress/e2e/login/login.cy.js', () => 
  require('../login/login.js'))
context('cypress/e2e/shopping-cart/checkout.cy.js', () => 
  require('../shopping-cart/checkout.cy.js'))
```

---

**Task to filter specs**

To filter tags dynamically, you need to copy some of the functions of `cypress-grep` into your project code.

First you need a task to find out which specs have the tag you want.

```js
module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('task', {
        specsWithTag: async ({tag}) => {
          const {globbySync} = await import('globby')
          const specFiles = globbySync(config.specPattern, {
            cwd: __dirname,
            ignore: config.excludeSpecPattern,
          })
          const regex = new RegExp(`{\\s*((tags)|(tag)):\\s*[',"]${tag}[',"]\\s*}`)
          return specFiles.filter(spec => {
            const fullPath = path.join(__dirname, spec)
            const specCode = fs.readFileSync(fullPath, { encoding: 'utf8' })
            return regex.test(specCode)
          })
        }
      })
      return config
    },
  }
})
```

---

**Changes to the test generator**

Then you need to enhance the `_generate.cy.js` spec to handle tags.

Using `cypress-if` makes it easy to branch the code, depending on the filter entered.

```js
import 'cypress-if'

const specExtension = '.cy.js'

const filter = Cypress.$(parent.document.body)
  .find('div#app')
  .find('#inline-spec-list-header-search')
  .val()

const specList = Cypress.$(parent.document.body)
  .find('div#app .specs-list-container ul:eq(0) li')
  .map((index,el) => {
    const text = el.innerText.replace('\n', '').replace('\\', '/')
    const path = Cypress.$(el).find('a').attr('href').split('?file=')[1]
    return {
      text,
      path
    }
  })
  .filter((index, item) => {
    return item.text.endsWith(specExtension) && !item.text.startsWith('_')
  })
  .map((index,item) => item.path)
  .toArray()

const filterHasTag = (filter) => filter && filter.startsWith('@')

const generate = (specList, filter) => {
  const isTag = filterHasTag(filter)
  const indexSpecName = filter ? `_run-[${filter}]-${isTag ? 'tag' : 
    'filter'}${specExtension}` : `_run-all${specExtension}`
  const msg = `Processing ${isTag ? 'tag' : filter ? 'filter' : 'all'}: ${filter}`
  cy.log(msg)

  let content = `// generated script for specs filtered with "${filter}"\n\n`
  if (isTag) {
    content += `import cypressGrep from '@cypress/grep';\n`
    content += `Cypress.env('grepTags', '${filter}');\n`
    content += 'cypressGrep();\n\n'
  }
  content += specList.map(specPath => {
    return `context('${specPath}', () => require('..${specPath.replace('cypress/e2e', '')}'))`  
  }).join('\n')
  cy.writeFile(`./cypress/e2e/_generated-tests/${indexSpecName}`, content)
}

it('', () => {
  cy.wrap(filterHasTag(filter), {log:false})
    .if()
    .task('specsWithTag', {specs: specList, tag: '@smoke'})
    .then(tagged => generate(tagged, filter))
    .else()
    .then(() => generate(specList, filter))
})
```