# Using cypress grep tags how can we configurable tags for a automation tests

Tags: cypress, cypress-grep

How can we make the cypress grep tags configurable for a automation tests. At the moments the tags are predefined in side the automation tests, for example: `"@Smoke"`. This is running fine. But now I want to run few tests with a new tag like `@QuickRun` from gitBash CLI and it should pick up those tests having tagged with a global variable ?
I have tried as following, I have passed the "@QuickRun" from the CLI and receiving inside the test to a const variable `onFlyTag`, but not working at the moment. Is it possible, could someone please advise.

//GitBash CLI

```
CYPRESS_BASE_URL=https://staging-qa-bookingtesting.com/ npx cypress run --env grepTags="@quickRun",ENV="staging" --browser chrome
```

//login.spec.js

```
const onFlyTag = Cypress.env("grepTags");

    it(
        "Test-1",
        { tags: ["@Smoke", "@LoginLogout", "@Regression", `"${onFlyTag}"` ] },
         //..rest of the test follows here...
      );

    it(
        "Test-2",
        { tags: ["@Smoke", "@LoginLogout", "@Regression"] },
         //..rest of the test follows here...
      );

    it(
        "Test-3",
        { tags: ["@Smoke", "@LoginLogout", "@Regression", `"${onFlyTag}"`] },
         //..rest of the test follows here...
      );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work if you remove the double-quotes from inside the string template:

// Spec grep-tags.cy.js

```js
const onFlyTag = Cypress.env("grepTags");

it(
  "Test-1",
  { tags: ["@Smoke", "@LoginLogout", "@Regression", `${onFlyTag}`] },
  () => { expect(true).to.eq(true) }
);

it(
  "Test-2",
  { tags: ["@Smoke", "@LoginLogout", "@Regression"] },
  () => { expect(true).to.eq(true) }
);

it(
  "Test-3",
  { tags: ["@Smoke", "@LoginLogout", "@Regression", `${onFlyTag}`] },
  () => { expect(true).to.eq(true) }
);
```

**Other config**

// cypress/support/e2e.js

```js
import './commands'
import cypressGrep from '@cypress/grep';
cypressGrep();
```

// package.json

```js
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "cy:quick": "npx cypress run --spec 'cypress/e2e/grep-tags.cy.js' --env grepTags='@quickRun'"
  }
}
```

**Output result**

```js
===================================================================================

  (Run Starting)

  ┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
  │ Cypress:        12.3.0                                                                     
  │ Browser:        Electron 106 (headless)                                            
  │ Node Version:   v18.12.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)                                   
  │ Specs:          1 found (grep-tags.cy.js)                                                     
  │ Searched:       ...cypress\e2e\grep-tags.cy.js              
  └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

  Running:  grep-tags.cy.js                                                (1 of 1)


  √ Test-1 (66ms)
  - Test-2
  √ Test-3 (36ms)

  2 passing (128ms)
  1 pending
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. Sorry I am getting below error..
`Oops...we found an error preparing this test file:

  > cypress\support\e2e.js

The error was:

Error: Webpack Compilation Error
./cypress/support/e2e.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@cypress/grep' in 'C:\Project\work\end-to-end-automation\cypress\support'
resolve '@cypress-grep' in 'C:\Project\work\end-to-end-automation\cypress\support'
  Parsed request is a module`

Comment: I have used your import method as follows...
`import cypressGrep from "@cypress/grep";
cypressGrep();`

and commented the existing approach 
require("cypress-grep")();

Comment: Also what do think about the approach that i have used in my tests to get the tag values ? is there any other better way that you can suggest please ?

Comment: Thanks for you comments, it looks like you may be using the deprecated version of cypress grep - but the only change you need is the first line (re double quotes). The rest is so that the public can reproduce the example - as you can see it does work.

Comment: I take it you have a bigger picture in mind for this technique. It's certainly a good idea to have dynamic tags available in the tool box. I did something similar here [Filter tests by tags (e.g cypress-grep)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74355377/16997707) if you're interested, this is to use tags on the fly for filtering test in Open mode. Your way looks more straight-forward.