# How to call a test suite from another test case in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress, test-suite

The application I am working on requires me to call multiple test suites in the current testcase. I know that we can add the resuable command in `suport/commands.js` but that is not I am looking for.

testsuiteA.js

```
  describe(This should be called in another, function({
   .....
   })
  it(TestCase1,function(){....})
  it(TestCase2,function(){....})
```

I want to call the entire `testSuiteA` in a new testsuiteB or sometimes want to call only specific test cases of that suite. I tried some ways but I am stuck now.

Comment: I guess you could use the `cy.exec()` to your advantage. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `describe()` and `it()` blocks are JavaScript functions, you can create a function that calls them and export that function.

```js
// foo.js
export myTests function() {
  describe('Reusable tests', function () {
    // test content here
  });
}

// test-file.js
import { myTests } from "./foo.js" // import the function

myTests(); // run the tests
```

Comment: This is working for me, but when I try to independently run `foo.js` it is failing with message `No tests found`

Comment: You would need to call `myTests()` in `foo.js` as well. Exporting the function does not run the function, and so Cypress would not see `foo.js` as having any tests.

Answer (score 4):

Running one spec inside another is possible with `import` or `require`,
see the general idea at [How to run all tests in one go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72498151/16997707)

Using `require()` is preferable if you want to structure `testSuiteB`:

```js
describe('testSuiteB', () => {
  context('it runs testSuiteA', () => {
    require('testSuiteA.js')
  })
  context('it runs testSuiteC', () => {
    require('testSuiteC.js')
  })
})
```

Doing it this way means you get a well formatted report, and you can still run `testSuiteA` independently (no function wrapper is required).